# Leaderboard from text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help on an assignment I am doing in Python 3.5.0. I have a leader board text file, which displays the top 5 scores of the program in order of where they are. I need some help putting them into an array, and then using this array to then output the leader board. The leaderboard is in the format of:

```
1. User1, Points
2. User2, Points
3. User3, Points
4. User4, Points
5. User5, Points
```

Thanks in advance

```
leaderboard = []
f = open('Leaderboard.txt','r')
for i in range(1,5):
    x = file.readline(i)
    leaderboard[i] = x
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include what you have already tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: ah ok sorry didnt see that

Comment: @Ruzihm is this better?

Comment: What @Ruzihm meant is that Stack Overflow is meant to solve problems in your existing code. He asked for you to put on the question what is your current code, and the exact problem you are facing. Here we don't answer the full code request to resolve an assigment. If you have no idea how to implement the code, perhaps you should take a look on Python's basic in order to come around with a solution, and if that solution fails, we will gladly help you out

Comment: Hi @Panda32. Just to help you out, check the following link. It will give you an idea about how to elaborate your question in a better way, so we can help you easily! :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, I can make a small model of my code quickly to show you what it is. The problem that I am facing is calling the text file into an array, which then should be sorted. The sorting bit isn't so important at the moment, it is more the calling it into the array and then being able to change it. Let me just install python quickly so i can show you

Comment: There @RodolfoDonãHosp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your loop all wrong. Don't assume how many lines your file has.

```
# leaderboard = []
f = open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r')
leaderboard = [line.replace('\n','') for line in f.readlines()]


for i in leaderboard:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
1. User1, Points
2. User2, Points
3. User3, Points
4. User4, Points
5. User5, Points
```

Note that you should probably want to use `with`. If you want to use the file and not have to remember to close it afterwards:

```
with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r') as f:
    leaderboard = [line.replace('\n','') for line in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: I wasn’t assuming how many lines it has, the leaderboard only stores the top 5, and only 5 users will be using it as it has authentication. Also that wasn’t my actual code, I had to compile it quickly to give an example as I don’t have my actual code right now. And how does with actually work? I’ve never used it before

Comment: How does that array look inside the code? Like, will it be able to be sorted into numerical order

Comment: There is a lot of information you are not providing, like what is the output you actually want, sort the list based on what etc. I recommend you understand the code completely (google the functions that are used here), and when you have questions ask in Stack Overflow again

Comment: The output isn’t so important at the moment. The bit I need is to put the file into the array, where I can then sort it myself. I can already sort the list, but file handling is a massive weak point which I do not understand very well. The output will be at the end, after I have sorted and uploaded the new scores. Basically, the part I need is to upload the file line by line into my array (so 0 is 1., 1 is 2 etc) and then change that using my scores. Thanks :D

Comment: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. I'm out for today, but I recommend you to try it yourself, and if you fail, ask a new question in Stack Overflow with your concerns (Because this one is already answered, and many edits and comments are just making a mess)

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are not that good at file handling. First of all it's always smart to use:

```
with open("Leaderboard.txt", "r") as f:
    // do something
```

This is a built-in python method, with the first parameter being the file you are accessing. The second parameter is how you want to access the file, by putting "r" we're specifying that we want to read the file. You have more ways to access a file, "w" specifies that you also want to put something in the file. You have more, but that's beyond this question. The "as f" at the end basically stores the file in the variable, this variable you can then manipulate.

The next step is to verify that the data was read properly. You can use f.read() for this:

```
with open("Leaderboard.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
```

Try finding out what the data variable contains now on your own. I can tell you that it is a string. Now you can manipulate the string to your heart's content. Look at the other answers for what do to with the string to get your desired output.

You can also use data = f.readlines(), print the data to see what's different about it compared to using data = f.read()

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thanks, Im grateful for the help